# What does these error means getReadModeConfig, getReadModeRender, getReadModeExtract

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms, material-ui

Some of our users are getting these errors (getReadModeConfig, getReadModeRender, getReadModeExtract) on form submission. We are using react with Material UI for form. Don't know exactly what these errors mean. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I don't have any answers, but don't think it is to do with React or Material UI.  I've been seeing a very small number of the exact same errors - usually from the same users. I believe it is a browser extension but don't have any proof yet. In this particular app, I don't use React or Material UI (or any libraries, in fact).

Comment: I think this might be caused by the HeyTap browser.  All of these errors on my system have that user agent.

Comment: Even i'm seeing this in my web app since Sep 21st, my web app uses ReactJS

Comment: Yes, I'm also seeing some errors like these in my react app since last few weeks, not able to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: I have been seeing the same issue but with different browsers.

Comment: And i am using angular

Comment: I agree this looks like its not react specific, we had those pop in our sentry logs too in angular, it looks like they are triggered by button clics but I can not find anything else on these.

Comment: Also seeing these on a Vue app, and can confirm that the HeyTap browser is involved

Comment: I have an AngularJS (I know ancient times) app and the same error is happening and HeyTap is the browser

Answer (score 7):

I've also been seeing this error reported several times starting around 09/25, and the UA string is always the HeyTap Browser. I agree with what Dan Snoper said in his comment above: the error is most likely being caused by that browser, so I don't think there is anything we can do to fix or prevent it.

Comment: at least maybe can we know which line of code produces this? because in our sentry error event log, each (getReadModeConfig, getReadModeRender, getReadModeExtract) produce 1.1K events log.