# Cannot read property 'getReadModeConfig' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sentry, vercel

I am getting these three errors on Sentry:

```
Cannot read property 'getReadModeConfig' of undefined
Cannot read property 'getReadModeExtract' of undefined
Cannot read property 'getReadModeRender' of undefined
```

I have a static page build using React@17.0.1 and NextJS@11.1.2 hosted on [vercel.com](https://vercel.com). When I global searched these keywords, I have not found any such keyword being used in my codebase. These errors are breaking my website by invoking [NextJS Error handler](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-error-page#more-advanced-error-page-customizing). Can anyone help me rectify these errors?

Thank You.

Comment: I dont have the answer but this question seems relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64175183/what-does-these-error-means-getreadmodeconfig-getreadmoderender-getreadmodeext. Maybe because of an extension ?

Answer (score 1):

Sentry can catch any error that occurs in the page, including things like browser extensions or browser features.

As per [What does these error means getReadModeConfig, getReadModeRender, getReadModeExtract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64175183/what-does-these-error-means-getreadmodeconfig-getreadmoderender-getreadmodeext) it looks like the issue is related to the HeyTap Browser.

You can ignore such errors by [configuring Sentry](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/javascript/tips/#decluttering-sentry). In your case it could look something like this:

```js
const sentryOptions = {
  ignoreErrors: [
    "getReadModeConfig",
    "getReadModeExtract",
    "getReadModeRender",
  ]
}
```